# Make \maketitle span only one column in a twocolumn document

Tags: titles, two-column

I want to write a landscape two column document. Does anyone know if there's a possibility to use the `\maketitle` command such that the title is only in the left column and does not span the whole page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

When using the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to set your `landscape` and `twocolumn` mode, `\maketitle` behaves as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\author{An author}
\title{A title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, because the `twocolum` option doesn't set `if@twocolumn` to true. However, `geometry` also changes the page parameters, that might need to be reset anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This is the default of the article class. We can do a couple of patches to the `\maketitle` command (responsible for the title spanning the two columns) and to `\@maketitle`. The second set of patches is meant not to have the title vertically shifted down and start instead level with the second column.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Remove the brackets so LaTeX sees \twocolumn\@maketitle
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {[\@maketitle]}
  {\@maketitle}
  {}{}
% Remove the vertical shift from the title
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\null\vskip2em\begin{center}}
  {\vspace*{0pt}\nointerlineskip\begingroup\centering}
  {}{}
% In the final part we must remove \end{center}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\end{center}\par}
  {\par\endgroup}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\kant[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the observation that egreg make in his comment on Werner's answer, we can get a very simple solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Untitled}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@twocolumnfalse
\maketitle
\@twocolumntrue
\makeatother
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

All we had to do was pretend we're in one column mode :)